# My function returns an object not a task JSON

Tags: reactjs, redux

My function returns an object typed of option tag not a task JSON. This is my code:

```
         bringTasks = () =>{

                    return this.props.taskslist.map((task,index) => {

                        return (<option key={index} value={index}>{task.name}</option>);


                         })};
```

taskslist is the reducer, task is JSON object and option is tag I return.

The expected output is Example, "task 1 cleaning", but real output is "[object Object]".

What is wrong?, do you know which is the error?

Comment: seems something is not being parsed, what does `this.props.taskslist` look like when you console log it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work provided that taskslist is as expected:

```
 bringTasks(tasklist) {
   return tasklist.map((task,index) => {
     return (<option key={index} value={index}>{task.name}</option>);
 })};

  render() {

    return <div>{this.bringTasks(
    [
        {name: "name_1"},
      {name: "name_2"},
      {name: "name_3"}
    ]
    )}</div>;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jp3usvq6/2/